# make xml from result of wcf service's response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, logging, log4net

I wanna make a xml from result of my service's response in wcf,here is partial of my code which I can't log "serviceresult" in the following code :

```
public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
{
    logger.InfoFormat("InvokeEnd Start command operation:{0}", this.operationName);                        

    var serviceResult =  this.invoker.InvokeEnd(instance, out outputs, result);

    logger.InfoFormat("Method {0} - Result :{1}", this.operationName, result.ToString());
    return serviceResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do some XML serialization?

Like such:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());

x.Serialize(Console.Out,p);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
```

From: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815813

Comment: Thanks,but I used the code you gave me and after the execution of this line: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(serviceResult.GetType());    I've got this error: "There was an error reflecting type system System.Collection.Generic.List[myClass] "

Comment: What type are you passing into the serializer?

Comment: thanks mate-I checked the inner exception and also used your help and finally I solved ,thanks again